# Specific Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have one sample group. (I know my test statistics is nonparametric.)
My null hypothesis is a CI  and alternative is ~ . 
What is your idea for testing this hypothesis?

[image]

Comment: Can we test this hypothesis with 1-sample Wilcoxon, with mu=0 and then decision on confidence interval ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null hypothesis stated here is not a CI. It is just a given interval, confidence interval has a specific meaning in context of estimation. It is simply meaningless to call any interval as CI. And also the interval should be expressed as $[1.5,3]$.

You can approach this problem like this: do 2 hypothesis tests, first with $H_0=1.5$ $H_A<1.5$, $\alpha=.025$ and second with $H_0=3$, $H_A>3$, $\alpha=.025$. If both tests fail to reject $H_0$, you will fail to reject $H_0=[1.5,3]$, if one of them rejects $H_0$, you will reject $H_0=[1.5,3]$ with $\alpha=.05$ .

Comment: Thank you, Is not there any test for this hypothesis? Just one test, without bonferroni correction...

Comment: Can we test this hypothesis with 1-sample Wilcoxon, with mu=0 and then decision on confidence interval ?

Comment: I don't know of any single test taking $H_0$ as an interval. Typically you have to specify a value which will serve as mean of sampling distribution, from which p values are calculated.

By the way, you shouldn't confuse boundaries of rejection region as @WojciechF did in his answer. Those boundaries determine how large of a deviation should be considered as significantly different from value given in $H_0$. In this question you have multiple (actually infinitely many) values given in $H_0$ as an interval.

Comment: If you do 1-sample Wilcoxon, with mu=0, you test for $H_0: mu=0$ not for $H_0: mu \in [1.5,3]$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, You should measure the variable in your sample population and if its mean is between 1.5 and 3 then you should accept the null hypothesis; however if the measured mean is outside the given range then you should discard the null hypothesis and accept the alternative.

Comment: Can we test this hypothesis with 1-sample Wilcoxon, with mu=0 and then decision on confidence interval ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an equivalence test would do the trick. You are testing whether the mean is equivalent to 2.25 and you have your equivalence interval. Usually in equivalence testing you have two treatments (or whatever) to compare, but here you have one. It seems to me you could just use two one sample tests.

But I don't see a way to do it with one test. In a sense, the two tests above are one test - they are a test of a single hypothesis.

Comment: I doubted about hypothesis of 2.25, so asked this question.Which approach is better than else? 2.25 Or running of two tests?

Comment: It depends on what you want to find out.

Comment: Can you more explain, please?

Comment: What do you want to find out? If you want to find out if the mean (or median) is different from 2.25, test that. If you want to find out if it is outside the region you named, test that.